# How to start db2 after Ubuntu 9.10 upgrade? Missing libstdc++.so.5

Tags: ubuntu, db2

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 9.10 and now my db2 is not starting anymore. The error message reads as follows:

> db2start: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I guess, this is, because Ubuntu now uses version 6 as I can see in Synaptic. Is there a way, to tell DB2 to use the newer Version or do I have to Install the 5er Version? Will this somehow conflict with the 6er?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some threads about the same problem with other programs. The solution is to install the 5er version. It can be downloaded from http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/libstdc++5/download.

Answer (score 0):

go to http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?s=a48742e7c30667a202e19c7441ec3cb7&showtopic=840720 and download the older version from the site

Comment: As you can see, I already found a download sourc, added it as an answer and accepted it.